# Testing Data Annotations using Moq in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, moq

Does Moq properly take into account Data Annotations while testing a `Mock<DbContext>` and `Mock<DbSet<IEntity>>`? For instance, will the proper validation exceptions be thrown if I attempt to do something that is expressly forbidden by the Data Annotations of a Code First Entity Model?  If not, how can I properly test my expected results from Data Annotations?

edit: I should note that I am using Entity Framework 6, as it has been overhauled to work much better with Mock Frameworks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generally accepted wisdom in unit testing is "don't test code you don't own", so in this case even if `Moq` could do this (and it can't because as mentioned by Ela, it just provides fake implementations of certain parts of an interface) you shouldn't - you have to accept that the `DataAnnotations` provided by `System.ComponentModel` (or whichever) have been tested by their author, and work as advertised.

Of course if you have written your own custom attribute then you unit test this annotation validation code in a separate test class that tests its functionality independent of it being stacked onto a property.

Also, given that you have a Mock `DbContext` and `EntitySet`, I don't even see where DataAnnotations come into it - they would only be relevant in a unit test for some implementation *of an actual entity*, in which case you shouldn't be anywhere near a `DbContext` or `EntitySet` - you should be manually creating an entity (or mocking one) for the test at hand. Feel free to let us know what the context of these tests are!

Update:
In order to have a regression test for the presence of a specific attribute on a specific property, you could use reflection:

```
public void MyEntityClass_PropertyFoo_HasRequiredAttribute()
{
    var prop = typeof(MyEntity).GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(p=>p.Name=="Foo");
    if (prop!=null)
    {
        object[] attributes = prop.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(RequiredAttribute), true);
        if (attributes.Length==0)
        {
           //someone took it out, explode your test here.
        }
    }
}
```

I don't think there is any other reliable way to enforce that requirement, but then again I may well be wrong...

Comment: Right, but I'm not testing to make sure that the `DataAnnotations` work, I'm testing to make sure that they are present.  If somebody were to accidently refactor out a `[Required]` attribute, there should be a test somewhere that fails, don't you agree?

Comment: @JHixson, apologies - your question specifically states "will the proper validation exceptions be thrown if I attempt to do something that is expressly forbidden by the Data Annotations of a Code First Entity Model" but maybe I misunderstood it :)

Anyway - if you want to basically "lock down" that a specific field on your entity must have a `Required` attribute, why not just use a unit test with some reflection? I will update my answer shortly with some code.

Comment: Right, my lack of understanding of how mocking works caused me to word my question incorrectly.  I didn't realize that mocks were empty, and was hoping that if a `SaveChanges()` method would should fail in production because of validation, that method should fail in testing as well.  I see now that tests are supposed to be more specific than that, checking for one specific reason why a method should fail. Hence Mocking.

Comment: @JHixson, I see what you mean but because the validation done by those attributes is something that's invoked by the actual EF itself you would have an awful lot of mocking to do because you would have to mock the DbContext change tracking mechanism, for imho very limited benefit.

I'd say this kind of test is best left to the integration test phase where you are `SaveChanges()`-ing against a real database; either that or create a "proper" Stub `DbContext` that overrides `SaveChanges()` and in there you can manually invoke your validation and throw if needs be.

Answer (score 0):

Mock only gives you a "faked" object, it does not implement any functionality. It is just to control parts of your code or prevent null pointer exception because certain instances are not set up at all. But all methods which are not specifically set up within a mocked object will not do anything.

There are certain articles of how to unit test entity framework, maybe this helps.
For example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ff714955.aspx